# add and activate custom connect with SDK

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I try to add a custom connect with this article and it's working perfectly.

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-add-custom-connect-configuration-programmatically

I can't find the 'Status' property in the documentation

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/connect/connectconfigurations/create/

[image: connect]

How can I Activate programmatically this custom configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`allowEnvelopePublish`](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/connect/connectconfigurations/create/#schema__connectcustomconfiguration_allowenvelopepublish) attribute to `true` to turn on the configuration.

You're absolutely right that a better name for that attribute would have been `enabled` or somesuch.

Thank you for programmatically creating Connect configurations. It gives a much better user experience for the admin when your application takes care of the task.